# Where is it said that Yudhisthira gave 2640000 slaves to Brahmins for sexual purposes?

Tags: mahabharata, reference-request, sex, slavery

Where is it explicitly said that Yudhisthira gave 2640000 slaves to Brahminsfor sexual purposes?

Comment: Where did you hear that it was for _sexual_ purposes?

Comment: I have read MBH. Yudhisthira used to donate a lot. And used to survive on the things which were left after donating. After providing everything to his followers, servants and others, then he used to take anything for himself. He gave many male-female servants to brahmans, those were servants not slaves. And for sexual purpose!!! Nowhere it is written.